# Extract methods and input parameters from a WSDL web-service C#

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I wonder if there any way to extract the methods and the related input parameters from a WSDL web service in c#. Specifically i need a way to provide the endpoint URL of a web-service and get as a result the above information. Something like the "Add Service Reference" in VS. But what i want is to get those information by implementing a module and not by using any other tool. Does .NET provide any functions for that? I'm using .NET 4.5.

Thank you

Comment: That's a little vague.  You might consider adding a few more specifics or (better) and example of what you've tried or at least some pseudo-code for what you want.  It sounds like you want to download the WSDL as an XML Document (lots of options there) and then walk through it to get the Contracts.

Comment: Hi, What i actually need is to implement a dynamic module in which the user will be able to get an html page (pure html) by providing an endpoit URL and a method of this service. I hope that i'm more spesific now.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 good options that come with .NET and you need to access both from VS command prompt.

1. wsdl.exe -> this does exactly what you are looking for.
2. wcftestclient.exe -> this helps you test any webservice even before you add it to your project.

EDIT 1: I think I misread your question. Well you can always use the generated class file by WSDL.exe in your application.

Comment: Is there any ability to call the wsdl.exe programatically?